# Python getting SettingWithCopyWarning - iloc vs. loc - cannot figure out why

Tags: python, pandas, view, copy, warnings

I have the basic understanding of SettingWithCopyWarning but I am not able to figure out why I am getting the warning for this particular case.

I am following the code from https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb

When I run the code as below (using .loc), I do not get the SettingWithCopyWarning

However, if I run the code with .iloc instead, I do get the warning.

Can someone help me understand it?

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]

for set_ in (strat_train_set, strat_test_set):
    set_.drop("income_cat", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried resetting the index after using `iloc`? If you are parsing a subset, especially if you are creating/updating/computing for new values in the same dataframe that has been cut into a subset of the original, that warning tends to show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is not because of indexing, `iloc` and `loc` would work the same way for you here. The problem is in `set_.drop("income_cat", axis=1, inplace=True)`. It looks like there's a weak reference between the `set_` data frame and the `strat_train_set` and `strat_test_set`.

```
for set_ in (strat_train_set, strat_test_set):
         print(set_._is_copy)
```

With this you get:

```
<weakref at 0x128b30598; to 'DataFrame' at 0x128b355c0>
<weakref at 0x128b30598; to 'DataFrame' at 0x128b355c0>
```

This could lead to `SettingWithCopyWarning` as it's trying to transform the copy of the data frame and applying those change to the original ones as well.

Answer (score 1):

I did some exploration and according to my understanding this is what is under the hood of `SettingWithCopyWarning`: every time when a data frame `df` is created from another frame `df_orig`, `pandas` adopts some heuristics to determine whether the data **may be implicitly** copied from `df_orig`, which a less experienced user may not be aware of. If so, the `_is_copy` field of `df` is set to a [weak reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) of `df_orig`. Later, when an in-place update of `df` is attempted, `pandas` will determine whether a `SettingWithCopyWarning` should be shown based on `df._is_copy` as well as some other fields of `df` (note that `df._is_copy` is *not the sole criteria* here). However, since some methods are shared among different scenarios the heuristics is not perfect and some cases can be mishandled.

In the code from the post, both `housing.loc[train_index]` and `housing.iloc[train_index]` return an implicit copy of the `housing` data frame.

```
for df in (housing.loc[train_index], housing.iloc[train_index]):
    print(df._is_view, df._is_copy)
```

The above check yields the following result:

```
False None
False <weakref at 0x0000019BFDF37958; to 'DataFrame' at 0x0000019BFDF26550>
```

Here, `_is_view` is another field that shows whether an update on `df` could affect the original data frame `housing`. A `False` outcome indicates that the underlying data is already being copied. However, for `housing.loc[train_index]` the `df._is_copy` field is not set, which in my opinion should be in this case, resulting a missing `SettingWithCopyWarning` afterwards when an in-place modification of `df` is performed by the statement `df.drop("income_cat", axis=1, inplace=True)`.

In order to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`, you need to either (1) perform the in-place update before slicing; (2) if possible, build the update logic into slicing; or (3) make an "explicit" copy of the data after slicing when an in-place update is needed. In your example, approach (1) looks like this:

```
# Updates the housing data frame in-place before slicing
income_cat = housing["income_cat"]
housing.drop("income_cat", axis=1, inplace=True)

for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, income_cat):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

Approach (2) looks like this:

```
feature_cols = housing.columns.difference(["income_cat"])
for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    # Filter columns at the same time as slicing the rows
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index, feature_cols]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index, feature_cols]
```

Approach (3) looks like this:

```
for train_index, test_index in split.split(housing, housing["income_cat"]):
    ...

for set_ in (strat_train_set, strat_test_set):
    # Remove "inplace=True" results in a copy being made
    set_.drop("income_cat", axis=1)
```

Besides changing the `inplace` setting of the update method, [`df.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html#pandas.DataFrame.copy) is another method that can be used to make an "explicit" copy. If you intend to change one or more columns of `df`, use [`df.assign(col=...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a copy rather than `df["col"]=...`.